# Syntax for including and calling a Function within an ASP.net or ASPX page

Tags: asp.net

OK this is really silly but I don't do ASP much and I can't remember how to include a function or Sub within a page (to get some Code Reuse).

I really have looked for examples but can't find any.

I'd have thought it was as simple as:

<%
Function myFunction as string
  MyFunction="blah"
End Function
%>

'main code here

But.... I get a vague syntax error (below)  which I can't find any help one:

*Server Error in '/' Application.
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
Compiler Error Message: BC30035: Syntax error.
Source Error:*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VB.net example

```
<script runat="server">
    Function myFunction() As String 
        myFunction="blah"
    End Function
</script>
```

here's another example: http://www.808.dk/?code-aspnet-inline